# Using the Luhn/Mod 10 check with a long variable in Java

Tags: java, luhn

Hi I am having trouble with a homework problem asking me to use the Luhn/Mod 10 check in order to see if a credit card number fits the requirements for credit cards. Could someone please tell me how to tell the computer to read a digit from an inputted long variable? Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: 12345 % 10 is 5. 12345 / 10 is 1234. 1234 % 10 is 4. 1234 / 10 is 123.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the help!